# Plot is not visible in R markdown after knit

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have created a stacked bar in ggplot2.Each bar shows salerate of different itemcode.For some of the itemcode the sale rate is low and i am not able to see the written sale percentage properly due to oberlapping.How can i fix this?

This is my plot of itemcode based on sale:
[image: This is my plot of itemcode based on sale]

```
ggplot(data = sale1, aes(x = ItemCode,y = SaleRate , group = FromFranchise)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = FromFranchise))+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(SaleRate*100,1),"%")), position = 
position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            color="white")+
  xlab("Item Code")+
  ylab("Sale Rate")+
  ggtitle("Sale Rate Of Based On Item Code")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "dodgerblue4",size = 30,hjust = 
0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "dodgerblue4",size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "dodgerblue4",size = 20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.title = element_text(color = "dodgerblue4",size = 20),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.position = "none",
        legend.direction = "horizontal" ,
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Rmarkdown?

Comment: I can't try this myself because your question is not reproducible, but try adding + coord_flip() to your ggplot. That might free up some space and make the labels readable.

Comment: I am trying to add this plot to my r markdown file.The markdown file works properly but when i am pushing this markdown file to my github all the plots disappear.Sorry i forgot to mention this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option is to create a faceted chart around the FromFranchise variable. See the example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ItemCode       <- c(rep(c("2", "3", "4", "5"), each = 4))
FromFranchise  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
SaleRate       <- c(0.1, 0.05, 0.15, 0.18, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 0.09, 0.12, 0.2, 0.15, 0.14, 0.23, 0.1, 0.05)
sale1          <- data.frame(ItemCode, FromFranchise, SaleRate)

# original chart
ggplot(sale1, aes(x = ItemCode, y = SaleRate, fill = FromFranchise, label = SaleRate)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(SaleRate * 100, 1), "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white") +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Item Code", y = "Sales Rate", title = "Sale Rate Of Based On Item Code")
```

[image]

```r
# faceted chart
ggplot(sale1, aes(x = ItemCode, y = SaleRate, fill = FromFranchise)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(SaleRate * 100, 1), "%")), vjust = -0.3) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ FromFranchise) +
  ylim(0, 0.3) +
  labs(x = "Item Code", y = "Sales Rate", title = "Sale Rate Of Based On Item Code")
```

[image]